# Perl sqrt, cube issue: 1 showing up after each line

Tags: shell, perl

I am having a tiny issue with a small perl script using arithmetic operators. After my cube root, and square root operators, a 1 shows up. I was testing this script on an openSUSE 42.1 VM.

I'm just not too certain what the 1 after each line is, I have tried looking it up, but am not too certain. I mainly script in bash, and ksh, so this perl syntax is a bit new to me.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Provide a sum, cube of the sum, and square root of the sum of three set variables
# Set variables
$v1=10;
$v2=9;
$v3=8;
$val=$v1+$v2+$v3;
$cube=$val ** (1/3);
$square= sqrt($val);
print "Sum of 10, 9, 8: $val\n";
print
print "Cube of Sum: $cube\n";
print
print "Square of Sum: $square\n";
print
print "Thanks for using this script!"
```

Comment: The first 2 lines of a perl script, after the shebang, should always be `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Answer (score 9):

Your lines just saying

```
print
```

are not statements in themselves as they are not terminated by a `;`. Instead they are part of statements of the form

```
print print "text";
```

The inner print has an argument of "text" and prints that, the outer print has an argument of `print "text"` and print the value of that, and when succesful print returns a value of 1 (perldoc only says it returns true, so don't rely it being 1) - so a 1 is printed.

If the point was to format your output nicely, you should explicitly print `"\n"`.

Comment: In other words, fix by adding a `;` to the end of the lines with only `print` on them.  As a general rule, all `perl` statements need a `;` to terminate them unless they are the last statement of a block or the last statement of a file.

Comment: @cas: That doesn't help. A statement like `print;` is the same as `print $_;`. In this case it would have printed nothing because the "it" variable `$_` has never been defined. If you want a blank line then you must `print "\n"`

Comment: my goal was not to fix every minor problem with the OP's script (if it was, i'd start by using a single multi-line print statement, not multiple `print "..."`s and `print "\n";`s).  It was to highlight the fact that the missing `';` was the source of the problem, and to let them know that perl statements need to be terminated with `;`s.

Answer (score 2):

As has been explained, half of your `print` calls are printing the return value of the following `print` statement because you are missing a semicolon at the end of the line to terminate the statement

Also, `print` on its own will print the value of the default variable `$_`, not a newline as you expected. You need to write `print "\n";` to achieve what you intend

It's also *very important* to add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of every Perl program you write. You will also need to declare all of your variables using `my`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# Provide a sum, cube of the sum, and square root of the sum of three set variables
# Set variables

my $v1     = 10;
my $v2     = 9;
my $v3     = 8;
my $val    = $v1 + $v2 + $v3;
my $cube   = $val**( 1 / 3 );
my $square = sqrt($val);

print "Sum of 10, 9, 8: $val\n";
print "\n";
print "Cube root of Sum: $cube\n";
print "\n";
print "Square root of Sum: $square\n";
print "\n";
print "Thanks for using this script!\n";
print "\n";
```

#### output

```
Sum of 10, 9, 8: 27

Cube root of Sum: 3

Square root of Sum: 5.19615242270663

Thanks for using this script!
```

It's also worth pointing out that there's a construct called a *here document* that will let you do this more neatly and clearly. If you change those print statements to just one, like this, then the intention is clear and the output is identical to that of the original code

```
print <<END;
Sum of 10, 9, 8: $val

Cube root of Sum: $cube

Square root of Sum: $square

Thanks for using this script!

END
```

Answer (score 0):

As Henrik states in his answer, the lines with `print` and no `;` are the problem.

An alternate way to get Perl to print a blank line between the main lines of output is to add an addition new line character, `\n`, at the end of each of the print lines. The code would become:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Provide a sum, cube of the sum, and square root of the sum of three set variables
# Set variables
$v1=10;
$v2=9;
$v3=8;
$val=$v1+$v2+$v3;
$cube=$val ** (1/3);
$square= sqrt($val);
print "Sum of 10, 9, 8: $val\n\n";
print
print "Cube of Sum: $cube\n\n";
print
print "Square of Sum: $square\n\n";
print
print "Thanks for using this script!"
```

The output is:

```
Sum of 10, 9, 8: 27

Cube of Sum: 3

Square of Sum: 5.19615242270663
```

By the way, your equation for calculating the cube of the sum calculates the cubed root. To calculate the cube of the sum you need,

```
$cube=$val ** (3);
```

Likewise, your equation to find the square of the sum is calculating the square root, not the square. To find the square of the sum you need to raise the sum to the power of 2.